# javascript convert buffer to a number

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, buffer

I have a buffer with size n(assume it's very large and will not have index overflow). I want to hash the first 16 bytes of the buffer and use the hash result as the next location in the buffer to hash the next following 16 bytes, and so on and so forth. This is my first line of code:

```js
var newLocation = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(buf.slice(0, 16)).digest()
```

newLocation is actually a buffer type. I want to know how can I convert it to an index number that I can jump to `buf.slice(index, 16)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want 16 BIT LE integer. Try `newLocation = newLocation.readInt16LE(0);`

Or simply, `newLocation = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(buf.slice(0, 16)).digest().readInt16LE(0);`

If you want BE, use `readInt16BE` instead.

---

If you really mean 16 bytes, I don't know how to convert a 16 bytes buffer into an integer.

Comment: Is it possible that I can map the hash value to an N-bit number which N can be vary? For example, if I want a 256-bit index, can I convert directly from newLocation? Thanks.

Comment: 16 Bytes is the length of data as an input to the hash function. The length of the hash value is 256 bits, which is 32 Bytes. I guess use digest('binary') will result a 256-bit binary string. However, is it possible that I can map the hash value to an N-bit number which N can be vary? For example, if I want a 128-bit or 512-bit index, can I convert directly from newLocation? Thanks.

Comment: @LuqinWang You can, but a N-bit number might be very huge when N is larger than 16, let alone 256. Considering that you are going to use this number as the index of an array, this array are very possible to be larger than your memory capacity. I really don't know why you want to do it.